# How to mention that someone has similar qualities to us and we can make friends with them?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-request, phrase-request

Has the word "type" been used correctly in the following sentence? (I'm suspicious about it, because in the Longman dictionary it is stated that "be sb's type: to be the kind of person someone is sexually attracted to")

> When we go to a museum we can **mingle** with some visitors which are of **our type** and make friends with them.

By the way, is it okay to use "mingle" as I did?

Edit:

This is a screenshot taken from the dictionary.(In response to  user3169)
[image]

Comment: Could you add a link to the dictionary definition you mention? I don't agree with their definition and wonder if there is something else.

Comment: A note: I've been told that we don't usually use **which** with people, and this **[ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=visitors+who+are%2Cvisitors+which+are&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cvisitors%20who%20are%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cvisitors%20which%20are%3B%2Cc0)** seems to confirm it.

Comment: @CopperKettle Thanks for your note. I agree with you in part, however it's not a general rule. Yes, it's a good idea to use **whom** in situations like this, however clearly we can use **which** as well. When you refer to the Longman dictionary you can find this example under the definition of which: "I don't know **which** of **us** was the more scared. "

Comment: @mok - thanks for the note! probably this preference to "who" refers more to relative clauses. I'll read up on the issue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not? You are right that it's also used for '[attraction](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/type_1)' but here, **in this context,** you are mixing up with visitors of *your types* and hence, sexuality is out of question.

The use of word *type* is okay over there.

> [She mixes with all types of people](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/type_1)

Stretching this...

> You *mix* with visitors of your *type*.

Though OALD writes *mix* over *mingle*, *mingle* is not incorrect! It's an idiomatic use.

> [mingle with someone- to mix with people](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/mingle+with)

Comment: Thanks. But regarding the second part of my question, isn't mingle a little bit more formal?

Comment: it's okay to use that! :) Answer edited!

Comment: The most common usage of "mingle" is when you meet people at a party or a social event. "While you are at the awards ceremony, be sure to **mingle** with the other guests. Who knows who you will meet." (AmE)

Answer (score 0):

I disagree with Maulik V's answer.

`She mixes with all types of people` is a different construction than `They are our type`, the latter of which (in my experience) almost always refers to some sort of attraction (romantic and the like).

The phrase `all [different] types of people` is like saying `all [different] colors of people`, but saying `she is your color` is a different construction than `your type` since "type" here has a different colloquial meaning indicating compatibility in a romantic or sexual nature when used in this way.

Lastly, `mingle` as used here is fine. As per a question in the comments, it's neutral, so neither formal nor informal, and would be appropriate in most cases where "relaxed meeting of (potentially new) people" is meant.

---

Some examples of what you could change the sentence to:

> When we go to a museum we can mingle with some **like-minded** visitors and make friends with them.

or

> When we go to a museum we can mingle with **the same sorts of people** and make friends with them.